# what is the default method in java?

Tags: java

I don't have any idea about how coding in java works. Because of my work I have to look into some java code. And one thing confused me. It seems we can have multiple classes for a single project but there is only one main function `public static void main()` for the project, and when the program runs the compiler first searches for that main function.

I have this code:

`First.java`

```
class First {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SecondClass example = new Second();
    }
}
```

`Second.java`

```
class Second {
    method1() {}
    method2() {}
}
```

So, now when the `Second` class runs, which method runs at first ? Like in php the `index()` function runs at the beginning by default.

Guys, I may have sounded really stupid at places and I'm sorry about it.

Comment: Unless you invoke a method in `Second`, nothing will be invoked

Comment: When you instantiate `Second`, it would look to execute its constructor. But in your case, there is none, so nothing is executed.

Comment: To invoke one of the methods you would need to do `example.method1();` and then that would call method one. Unless you made the methods private in which case you wouldnt be able to access them from your class First

Comment: For the sake of completeness: there can actually be multiple `main`-methods in a project (only one per class, though). One parameter of the `java` console command is the name of the class which contains the main method to be executed. And in a JAR file, the manifest would point to the class that serves as entry point.

Comment: @Rudy M, your claim about the `Second` constructor that "in your case, there is none, so nothing is executed" is false. `Second` has a no-arg constructor that throws no checked exceptions, per the Java Language Specification, and the example code calls it. However, it won't be executed if the example code doesn't compile, which it won't unless `SecondClass` (terrible name) is a supertype of `Second`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method you call/invoke in your `main method` will be executed first. For example, if you call `method1()` first, it will be executed first, and so on...

Below, I provide you, an example that can help you.

`HelloWorld.java`

```
public class HelloWorld{

    public static void main(String[] args){

    Hello he = new Hello();
    he.sayHelloToMe(); // if you replace this line by he.sayHelloToYou(); then this method will execute at the first place
    he.sayHelloToYou();
    }
}

class Hello{

    public void sayHelloToMe()
    {
        System.out.println("Hello to me!");
    }

    public void sayHelloToYou()
    {
        System.out.println("Hello to you!");
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

It just creates a new object of type Second,  but does not run any of the methods.

Answer (score 3):

There is no constructor in your `Second` class. Otherwise, it would execute upon you creating an instance of `Second`. Your methods in `Second` will not execute. You'd have to write something like `example.method1()`.

Answer (score 3):

Like everyone is saying currently, the `SecondClass` isn't actually doing anything.  In terms of PHP, the `index()` method that you are referring to would be the `main` method in the `First` class.  That's your entry point for the program, much like the entry point to your website that is using PHP.  The `Second` class is more like another webpage that doesn't actually do anything until you call out to it.  I would highly recommend getting a developer to look at the code though as it seems like you are way out of your element and could cause more harm to your code than help.  Best of lucky in doing what you need to get done though.

Answer (score 2):

In the first image you have (or tried to) created an object of the Second class. That is the first step to invoke your methods in Second class.Correct way is,

```
Second example = new Second();
```

After you have created an object, you can invoke the methods of that object.For an example, here you can invoke the two methods using,

```
example.method1();
example.method2();
```

Order of methods executed will depend on the order you call the methods.

Hope this helps. :)